# Is there a way to edit a pdf with C# .net core?

Tags: .net, pdf, .net-core, .net-standard

I would like to know if there is any way to edit the pdf using c# .net core, just to replace some words

Comment: PDF is not designed to be edited. The best you can get is to paint over existing text. No reflow of existing text, it is up to you to match font and line up to existing text

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) provides two options for replacement of static text on a page:

1. Copy page objects and change specific text chunks. Basic sample:
   https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/CopyPageObjects

   In the `drawText` method you can check PdfTextData.Text value and draw another text instead (replace `target.DrawString(td.GetCharacterCodes());` call)

   For example, this code replaces all occurrences of "have" on the first page with "has":

   ```cs
   using System.Diagnostics;

   namespace BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf.Samples
   {
       public static class CopyPageObjects
       {
           public static void Main()
           {
               // NOTE: 
               // When used in trial mode, the library imposes some restrictions.
               // Please visit http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/trial-restrictions.aspx
               // for more information.

               const string PathToFile = "CopyPageObjects.pdf";

               using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(@"C:\Work\BitMiracle\Docotic\QPdf\Futura_font.pdf"))
               {
                   using (PdfDocument copy = pdf.CopyPages(0, 1))
                   {
                       PdfPage sourcePage = copy.Pages[0];
                       PdfPage copyPage = copy.AddPage();

                       copyPage.Rotation = sourcePage.Rotation;
                       copyPage.MediaBox = sourcePage.MediaBox;
                       if (sourcePage.CropBox != sourcePage.MediaBox)
                           copyPage.CropBox = sourcePage.CropBox;

                       PdfCanvas target = copyPage.Canvas;
                       foreach (PdfPageObject obj in sourcePage.GetObjects())
                       {
                           target.SaveState();
                           setClipRegion(target, obj.ClipRegion);

                           if (obj.Type == PdfPageObjectType.Path)
                           {
                               PdfPath path = (PdfPath)obj;
                               target.Transform(path.TransformationMatrix);

                               if (path.PaintMode == PdfDrawMode.Fill || path.PaintMode == PdfDrawMode.FillAndStroke)
                                   setBrush(target.Brush, path.Brush);

                               if (path.PaintMode == PdfDrawMode.Stroke || path.PaintMode == PdfDrawMode.FillAndStroke)
                                   setPen(target.Pen, path.Pen);

                               appendPath(target, path);
                               drawPath(target, path);
                           }
                           else if (obj.Type == PdfPageObjectType.Image)
                           {
                               PdfPaintedImage image = (PdfPaintedImage)obj;
                               target.TranslateTransform(image.Position.X, image.Position.Y);
                               target.Transform(image.TransformationMatrix);

                               setBrush(target.Brush, image.Brush);
                               target.DrawImage(image.Image, 0, 0, 0);
                           }
                           else if (obj.Type == PdfPageObjectType.Text)
                           {
                               PdfTextData text = (PdfTextData)obj;
                               drawText(target, text);
                           }

                           target.RestoreState();
                       }

                       copy.RemovePage(0);

                       copy.Save(PathToFile);
                   }
               }

               Process.Start(PathToFile);
           }

           private static void setClipRegion(PdfCanvas canvas, PdfClipRegion clipRegion)
           {
               if (clipRegion.IntersectedPaths.Count == 0)
                   return;

               PdfMatrix transformationBefore = canvas.TransformationMatrix;
               try
               {
                   foreach (PdfPath clipPath in clipRegion.IntersectedPaths)
                   {
                       canvas.ResetTransform();
                       canvas.Transform(clipPath.TransformationMatrix);
                       appendPath(canvas, clipPath);
                       canvas.SetClip(clipPath.ClipMode.Value);
                   }
               }
               finally
               {
                   canvas.ResetTransform();
                   canvas.Transform(transformationBefore);
               }
           }

           private static void setBrush(PdfBrush dst, PdfBrushInfo src)
           {
               PdfColor color = src.Color;
               if (color != null)
                   dst.Color = color;

               dst.Opacity = src.Opacity;

               var pattern = src.Pattern;
               if (pattern != null)
                   dst.Pattern = pattern;
           }

           private static void setPen(PdfPen dst, PdfPenInfo src)
           {
               PdfColor color = src.Color;
               if (color != null)
                   dst.Color = color;

               var pattern = src.Pattern;
               if (pattern != null)
                   dst.Pattern = pattern;

               dst.DashPattern = src.DashPattern;
               dst.EndCap = src.EndCap;
               dst.LineJoin = src.LineJoin;
               dst.MiterLimit = src.MiterLimit;
               dst.Opacity = src.Opacity;
               dst.Width = src.Width;
           }

           private static void appendPath(PdfCanvas target, PdfPath path)
           {
               foreach (PdfSubpath subpath in path.Subpaths)
               {
                   foreach (PdfPathSegment segment in subpath.Segments)
                   {
                       switch (segment.Type)
                       {
                           case PdfPathSegmentType.Point:
                               target.CurrentPosition = ((PdfPointSegment)segment).Value;
                               break;

                           case PdfPathSegmentType.Line:
                               PdfLineSegment line = (PdfLineSegment)segment;
                               target.CurrentPosition = line.Start;
                               target.AppendLineTo(line.End);
                               break;

                           case PdfPathSegmentType.Bezier:
                               PdfBezierSegment bezier = (PdfBezierSegment)segment;
                               target.CurrentPosition = bezier.Start;
                               target.AppendCurveTo(bezier.FirstControl, bezier.SecondControl, bezier.End);
                               break;

                           case PdfPathSegmentType.Rectangle:
                               target.AppendRectangle(((PdfRectangleSegment)segment).Bounds);
                               break;

                           case PdfPathSegmentType.CloseSubpath:
                               target.ClosePath();
                               break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           private static void drawPath(PdfCanvas target, PdfPath path)
           {
               switch (path.PaintMode)
               {
                   case PdfDrawMode.Fill:
                       target.FillPath(path.FillMode.Value);
                       break;

                   case PdfDrawMode.FillAndStroke:
                       target.FillAndStrokePath(path.FillMode.Value);
                       break;

                   case PdfDrawMode.Stroke:
                       target.StrokePath();
                       break;

                   default:
                       target.ResetPath();
                       break;
               }
           }

           private static void drawText(PdfCanvas target, PdfTextData td)
           {
               target.TextRenderingMode = td.RenderingMode;
               setBrush(target.Brush, td.Brush);
               setPen(target.Pen, td.Pen);

               target.TextPosition = PdfPoint.Empty;
               target.FontSize = td.FontSize;
               target.Font = td.Font;
               target.CharacterSpacing = td.CharacterSpacing;
               target.WordSpacing = td.WordSpacing;
               target.TextHorizontalScaling = td.HorizontalScaling;

               target.TranslateTransform(td.Position.X, td.Position.Y);
               target.Transform(td.TransformationMatrix);

               if (!td.Text.Contains("have"))
                   target.DrawString(td.GetCharacterCodes());
               else
                   target.DrawString(td.Text.Replace("have", "has"));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Hide existing text chunk and draw new text above.
   You can try to draw new text in a readonly textbox without border over rectangle:

   ```cs
   using (PdfDocument pdf = ..)
   {
       // "replace" text - hide existing text and draw a new one.
       PdfPage page = pdf.Pages[0];
       PdfCanvas canvas = page.Canvas;
       foreach (PdfTextData word in page.GetWords())
       {
           if (word.Text == "text_to_replace")
           {
               PdfRectangle rectangleToHide = word.Bounds;

               canvas.Brush.Color = new PdfRgbColor(255, 255, 255);
               canvas.DrawRectangle(rectangleToHide, PdfDrawMode.Fill);

               // Draw new string in a readonly text box. This solution restricts selection of the old string.
               PdfTextBox textBox = page.AddTextBox(rectangleToHide);
               textBox.HasBorder = false;
               textBox.ReadOnly = true;
               textBox.Font = word.Font;
               textBox.FontSize = word.FontSize * word.TransformationMatrix.M22;
               textBox.Text = "new text";
           }
       }

       pdf.Save(..);
   }
   ```

Comment: Probably worth noting the $1000 minimum price tag minimum

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this nuget package [sautinsoft.document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sautinsoft.document/)

To replace the word, they have an example in [their documentation](https://www.sautinsoft.com/products/document/examples/find-replace-content-net-csharp-vb.php):

```
using System.IO;
using SautinSoft.Document;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Sample
{
    class Sample
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FindAndReplace();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find and replace a text using ContentRange.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Details: https://sautinsoft.com/products/document/examples/find-replace-content-net-csharp-vb.php
        /// </remarks>
        public static void FindAndReplace()
        {
            // Path to a loadable document.
            string loadPath = @"..\..\critique.pdf";

            // Load a document intoDocumentCore.
            DocumentCore dc = DocumentCore.Load(loadPath);

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"bean", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            //Find "Bean" and Replace everywhere on "Joker :-)"
            // Please note, Reverse() makes sure that action replace not affects to Find().
            foreach (ContentRange item in dc.Content.Find(regex).Reverse())
            {
                item.Replace("Joker");
            }

            // Save our document into PDF format.
            string savePath = "Replaced.pdf";
            dc.Save(savePath, new PdfSaveOptions());

            // Open the result for demonstration purposes.
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(loadPath) { UseShellExecute = true });
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(savePath) { UseShellExecute = true });
        }
    }
}
```

It's really simple :)

Comment: This sample changes text in a DOCX document and not in PDF.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, the logic is exactly the same. I tested it in my application and it works well.

Comment: I tested this with my old simple [test document](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/test.pdf), replacing "Test" or "Dokument" by "Überprüfung" or "stet". Indeed, it replaced the text **but** in each case it replaced the font by a completely different one. As the font only is subset embedded, it would have been acceptable to have the replacement  "Überprüfung" using a different font. When replacing with "stet", though, all glyphs in the original font were present, so switching fonts is not explainable here.

Comment: So essentially this replacement may work cleanly in some cases but one has to be aware that it also can introduce unwanted changes even outside the actually changed content ranges. For production use this means that it can be used for controlled input (e.g. for documents from a number of PDF generators tested against this routine) but not for arbitrary input documents (e.g. uncontrolled uploads by users).

Answer (score 0):

There is [aspose.pdf](https://products.aspose.com/pdf), a commercial product that offers you this feature for .NET Framework, .NET Core, Java and C++